# How to efficiently loop through the lines of a file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a file `example.txt` with about 3000 lines with a string in each line. A small file example would be:

```
>cat example.txt
saudifh
sometestPOIFJEJ
sometextASLKJND
saudifh
sometextASLKJND
IHFEW
foo
bar
```

I want to check all repeated lines in this file and output them. The desired output would be:

```
>checkRepetitions.sh
found two equal lines: index1=1 , index2=4 , value=saudifh
found two equal lines: index1=3 , index2=5 , value=sometextASLKJND
```

I made a script `checkRepetions.sh`:

```
#!bin/bash
size=$(cat example.txt | wc -l)
for i in $(seq 1 $size); do
i_next=$((i+1))
line1=$(cat example.txt | head -n$i | tail -n1)
for j in $(seq $i_next $size); do
line2=$(cat example.txt | head -n$j | tail -n1)
if [ "$line1" = "$line2" ]; then
echo "found two equal lines: index1=$i , index2=$j , value=$line1"
fi
done
done
```

However this script is very slow, it takes more than 10 minutes to run. In python it takes less than 5 seconds... I tried to store the file in memory by doing `lines=$(cat example.txt)` and doing `line1=$(cat $lines | cut -d',' -f$i)` but this is still very slow...

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @EdMorton I edited it, I think now it's clear

Comment: Sounds like you should take a look at the sort and uniq commands.

Comment: @EdMorton I want an efficient solution, if the file has ten lines, I can easily do it easily with my code, but ok edit it.

Comment: @Pedro, ...if you want a maximally efficient solution, bash is the wrong tool for the job. Though all the command substitutions, external command invocations, &c. make your code many base-10 orders  of magnitude (which is to say, yes, hundreds or thousands of times) less efficient than it could be -- a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop is generally the Right Thing if you aren't so performance-sensitive that a different language is preferable altogether.

Comment: ...it's also worth noting that GNU `uniq` has built-in support for finding repeated lines in sorted input (such as that `sort` emits). There are higher startup costs, but you'll get better behavior with large files -- `sort` is able to use temporary files to handle inputs larger than memory, for example, which a native `awk` approach can't do.

Comment: @Pedro, ...btw, out of curiosity, how many lines of input is it for which you clocked the 10-minute benchmark? (Being exponential-time, it shouldn't take long to get there, but I'm a bit lazy to measure myself).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy he said his input file was 3,000 lines :-). I just tested in on a 3,000-line file created the same way as the 100,000 line file I tested our scripts against (see the bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020544/1745001)) and it was still running 30 mins later and still hadn't reached the end of the first 1,000 lines so I killed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why your script is so slow.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ val2hits[$0] = val2hits[$0] FS NR }
END {
    for (val in val2hits) {
        numHits = split(val2hits[val],hits)
        if ( numHits > 1 ) {
            printf "found %d equal lines:", numHits
            for ( hitNr=1; hitNr<=numHits; hitNr++ ) {
                printf " index%d=%d ,", hitNr, hits[hitNr]
            }
            print " value=" val
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
found 2 equal lines: index1=1 , index2=4 , value=saudifh
found 2 equal lines: index1=3 , index2=5 , value=sometextASLKJND
```

---

To give you an idea of the performance difference using a bash script that's written to be as efficient as possible and an equivalent awk script:

**bash:**

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.0 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# initialize an associative array, mapping each string to the last line it was seen on
declare -A lines=( )
lineNum=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
  (( ++lineNum ))
  if [[ ${lines[$line]} ]]; then
     printf 'Content previously seen on line %s also seen on line %s: %s\n' \
       "${lines[$line]}" "$lineNum" "$line"
  fi
  lines[$line]=$lineNum
done < "$1"

$ time ./tst.sh file100k > ou.sh
real    0m15.631s
user    0m13.806s
sys     0m1.029s
```

**awk:**

```
$ cat tst.awk
lines[$0] {
    printf "Content previously seen on line %s also seen on line %s: %s\n", \
       lines[$0], NR, $0
}
{ lines[$0]=NR }

$ time awk -f tst.awk file100k > ou.awk
real    0m0.234s
user    0m0.218s
sys     0m0.016s
```

There are no differences in the output of both scripts:

```
$ diff ou.sh ou.awk
$
```

The above is using 3rd-run timing to avoid caching issues and being tested against a file generated by the following awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=10000; i++) for (j=1; j<=10; j++) print j}' > file100k
```

When the input file had zero duplicate lines (generated by `seq 100000 > nodups100k`) the bash script executed in about the same amount of time as it did above while the awk script executed much faster than it did above:

```
$ time ./tst.sh nodups100k > ou.sh
real    0m15.179s
user    0m13.322s
sys     0m1.278s

$ time awk -f tst.awk nodups100k > ou.awk
real    0m0.078s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Comment: I disagree **strongly** with your link. The OP is using practices which are orders of magnitude slower than those the linked answer criticizes; replacing their code with that which is described as slow or efficient there would make it hundreds of times faster than it is right now.

Comment: Compared to the cost of `fork()`ing subshells and `exec()`ing separate `cat`, `head` and `tail` executables per line of input, the reasons described in that link are utterly inconsequential. The OP's code would be far faster doing a byte-by-byte read than it would be as it is now.

Comment: The linked article covers that and explains in laymans terms why that's a problem, for example: `Invoking a tool though has a cost ...A process has to be created, the tool has to be loaded, initialised, then cleaned-up, process destroyed and waited for. Invoking cut is like opening the kitchen drawer, take the knife, use it, wash it, dry it, put it back in the drawer`.

Comment: On a Mac, I'm seeing 7.079s third-run timing for the bash version, vs 0.328s for awk and 2.0s for ksh93 (which, being less than 3.2s, *is* within a single base-10 order of magnitude). Only change from the bash code is taking out the version check and using `typeset -A` rather than `declare -A`.

Answer (score 5):

When you do not want to use `awk` (a good tool for the job, parsing the input only once),
you can run through the lines several times. Sorting is expensive, but this solution avoids the loops you tried.

```
grep -Fnxf <(uniq -d <(sort example.txt)) example.txt
```

With `uniq -d <(sort example.txt)` you find all lines that occur more than once. Next `grep` will search for these (option `-f`) complete (`-x`) lines without regular expressions (`-F`) and show the line it occurs (`-n`).

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate a relatively efficient (within the limits of the language and runtime) native-bash approach, which you can see running in an online interpreter at https://ideone.com/iFpJr7:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.0 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# initialize an associative array, mapping each string to the last line it was seen on
declare -A lines=( )
lineNum=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
  lineNum=$(( lineNum + 1 ))
  if [[ ${lines[$line]} ]]; then
     printf 'found two equal lines: index1=%s, index2=%s, value=%s\n' \
       "${lines[$line]}" "$lineNum" "$line"
  fi
  lines[$line]=$lineNum
done <example.txt
```

Note the use of `while read` to iterate line-by-line, as described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001): *How can I read a file line-by-line (or field-by-field)?*; this permits us to open the file only once and read through it without needing any command substitutions (which fork off subshells) or external commands (which need to be individually  started up by the operating system every time they're invoked, and are likewise expensive).

The other part of the improvement here is that we're reading the whole file only once -- implementing an O(n) algorithm -- as opposed to running O(n^2) comparisons as the original code did.

Comment: To be clear - "relatively efficient" does still mean orders of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script :-). I thought that was the case but just tested it to be sure, see the bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020544/1745001) if you care...

Comment: Sure. 15sec for 100,000 lines is much, *much* faster than the OP's original code -- quite plausibly, fast enough to be suitable for their real-world use case.

Comment: @EdMorton, ...btw, any chance you'd be interested in benchmarking on ksh93, since you're taking measurements? Some minor syntax differences, yes, but that's a way to close much of the gap with awk while still being a POSIX-superset shell language.

Comment: Not particularly but more importantly i don't have ksh93 available right now (I'm running cygwin on my laptop). Would you expect there to be much of a difference in the timing between ksh93 and bash?

Comment: Yes -- ksh is generally far more performant than bash; I've seen well-written ksh93 code often be within a single base-10 order of magnitude of awk.

Comment: ...that said, I also wouldn't generally trust benchmarks taken on cygwin to be to be portable to other platforms -- a lot of common operations are much slower there than on traditional unixlikes.

Comment: FWIW my MO is - if you're **only** modifying text then just use awk, but if you're doing more than that (e.g. moving files, curling URLs, finding/killing processes, etc.) and need a loop then write the loop the way you did.