# cd to directory determined by pipelined commands

Tags: bash

I'm trying to parse a Window Title that contains a path and then cd to that directory. My command successfully returns the directory I want to go to but I'm getting weird problems when trying to cd to it. The window title looks like this: `C:\path\to\directory\file.cpp (bullet point)- Program name`.
Because of the weird bullet point symbol I'm cutting on the . in .cpp and then getting the parent directory of what it thinks is a subdirectory but is really a file. Still works fine. The command is

```
cd $(dirname $(tasklist -fi "imagename eq sublime_text.exe" -fo list -v | grep "Window Title" | cut -f1 -d. | cut -d: -f2- | cut -c 2-) | sed 's/^/"/ ;s/$/"/')
```

When I replace cd with echo I get `"C:\path\to\directory"` and when I simply type cd and copy paste this quoted path that I get back it works. But it will not work in the command, I get `bash: cd: "C:\Users\twilliams\Documents\GitHub\Native\mcs\src\Lib": No such file or directory`. I have also tried putting quotes around the cd and dirname commands like so

```
cd "$(dirname "$(tasklist -fi "imagename eq sublime_text.exe" -fo list -v | grep "Window Title" | cut -f1 -d. | cut -d: -f2- | cut -c 2-)" | sed 's/^ /"/;s/$/"/')"
```

Additionally I tried it using echo instead of sed like so

```
cd "$(echo "\"$(dirname "$(tasklist -fi "imagename eq sublime_text.exe" -fo list -v | grep "Window Title" | cut -f1 -d- | cut -d: -f2- | cut -c 2-)") \"")"
```

In all of these cases I get the proper `"C:\path\to\directory"` output when echoing, and cding to this path manually works

I'm using git bash on windows. Thoughts?

Comment: The distinction between literal and syntactic quotes is getting you here-. When you run `cd "foo"`, the `"`s are shell syntax, not part of the name. But if you run `var='"foo"'` and then run `cd "$var"` (or `cd $var`), the `"`s from inside the variable are literal, and `cd` tries to look for a path that contains them.

Comment: BTW, all those `cut`s are pretty nasty -- if you provided an example of the output you're trying to parse, I'd hazard we could probably provide a more robust alternative.

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is also useful background on the issue you're running into here. The important thing to grok, though, is that quotes *inside variables or strings* are data, not syntax; they aren't parsed as code. (It would be impossible to write shell scripts handling untrusted data safely otherwise!)

Comment: The return value of the `tasklist -fi "imagename eq sublime_text.exe" -fo list -v | grep "Window Title"` bit is `Window Title: C:\Users\twilliams\Documents\GitHub\Native\mcs\src\Tests\mr_create.cpp - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)` and I just need the path bit. So I chop off the window title, then everything after the . then there is a leading space that I get rid of. I suppoes window title is always going to be a static amount of characters so i can get rid of `cut -d: -f2-` and just change `cut -c 2-` to be `cut -c 15-`

Comment: I would actually be avoiding `cut` altogether in favor of the string manipulation practices discussed in [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) and the [bash-hackers' wiki page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: `title_line=$(tasklist -fi "imagename eq sublime_text.exe" -fo list -v | grep "Window Title" ); title_line=${title_line#*:}; title_line=${title_line%%"[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]"*}` may not be *exactly* the right thing, but it ought to be close.

Comment: ...or something like `path_re='([[:upper:]]:.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+'; if [[ $title_line =~ $path_re ]]; then echo "Found path: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi`

Comment: Out of curiosity what makes this approach better? I feel like I see cut used quite often

Comment: `cut` isn't actually part of the shell -- every time you use it, that's spinning up a completely separate executable. Similarly, to actually invoke it, you need to do something like `$(echo "foo" | cut)`, which *itself* `fork()`s off a subprocess after running `mkfifo()` to set up a pipeline to read its stdout, sets up to `wait()` for that subprocess to finish, etc.

Comment: ...part of why bash scripts has a record as being slow is that bash *is* a slow interpreter -- but offloading work to subprocesses (especially inside a loop!) introduces orders-of-magnitude of performance overhead you wouldn't have with native code, and also means you're using OS-vendor-provided tools, such that behavior can vary depending on which OS you're running your code on.

Comment: For a representative example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020353/how-to-efficiently-loop-through-the-lines-of-a-file-in-bash/52021238#comment90993234_52021238 -- 0.3 seconds to process 100,000 lines of input with awk, 2 seconds with ksh, 7 seconds with well-written bash, upwards of 10 minutes for bash that invoked a bunch of separate pipelines for every single line.

Comment: Interesting, so how is this? It works same as my original method had `function move(){
        var=$(tasklist -fi "imagename eq sublime_text.exe" -fo list -v | grep "Window Title")
        var=${var#*: }
        var=${var%\\*}
        cd $var
}`

Comment: Off-the-cuff, my first comments are a suggestion to be sure you always quote expansions (`cd "$var"`) to prevent unwanted string-splitting and globbing (if doing that breaks the code, it means the variables probably have unwanted whitespace in them and the PEs could be improved), and a suggestion to see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the `function` keyword (it's listed in multiple tables -- both the "few if any legitimate uses" table and the "use only with a specific reason" table).

Comment: ...I don't actually have a Cygwin box handy to test the proposed function, but one thing I'd do if I were debugging it in practice is test with `set -x` enabled.

Comment: (...just to clarify, tools like `cut` *can* be faster than native bash, but only if you're reusing a long-running instance across a long stream of input, not spinning up a new instance per loop entry; if you're genuinely curious, I could probably find a question discussing the distinction directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop inserting literal quotes -- unlike syntactic quotes they're treated as part of the directory name itself, and there isn't a drive named `"C` or a directory named `directory"` on your system. This can be as simple as just taking out the `sed` invocation:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(tasklist -fi "imagename eq sublime_text.exe" -fo list -v |
                 grep "Window Title" |
                 cut -f1 -d. |
                 cut -d: -f2- |
                 cut -c 2-)")"
```

By the way, I'd also suggest using `cygpath` to convert your Windows-style filename over to a natively-UNIXy one that doesn't require cygwin-specific magic to be processed.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Didn't realize there was a difference between literal quotes and syntactic quotes